# event on minimum length using js

Tags: javascript, input

need to add error text by using js - If user  type only 3 character in the field. How to do it? Thanks

```
<body>
<input type="text" class="user-input" minlength="4">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern attribute validation.

```
 <input pattern=".{3,}"   required title="3 characters minimum">
<input pattern=".{5,10}" required title="5 to 10 characters">
```

If you want to create the option to use the pattern for "empty, or minimum length" use like below

```
<input pattern=".{0}|.{5,10}" required title="Either 0 OR (5 to 10 chars)">
<input pattern=".{0}|.{8,}"   required title="Either 0 OR (8 chars minimum)">
```

Answer (score -1):

you could retrieve its value from the id:

```
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName['user-input'].value;

        if (x.length < 4) {
            alert(`please enter at least ${x.length} characters`);
            return false;
        }
```